# After macOS Sierra Update, Eject USB trigger hard-reset

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, macos-sierra

I'm using Android Studio and Samsung Galaxy S4. After updated macOS Sierra devPreview version. When I eject phone USB connection, my Retina MacBook Pro MID2015 freeze and not response. (Two times I encountered with this) I need to enforce hard-reset with keyboard hold power key. After restart it gives me below error.

What does it mean? What I need to. I informed as bug report.

```
Tue Jun 28 12:53:54 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff8002cb260e): Preemption level underflow, possible cause unlocking an unlocked mutex or spinlock
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9238053c00 : 0xffffff8002d0475c
0xffffff9238053c80 : 0xffffff8002cb260e
0xffffff9238053c90 : 0xffffff8002cb232f
0xffffff9238053ca0 : 0xffffff800329473b
0xffffff9238053cf0 : 0xffffff80032957a0
0xffffff9238053d40 : 0xffffff80032ed07e
0xffffff9238053db0 : 0xffffff8002dce792
0xffffff9238053e00 : 0xffffff8002d092e9
0xffffff9238053e40 : 0xffffff8002ce6eb1
0xffffff9238053e90 : 0xffffff8002cfaca1
0xffffff9238053f10 : 0xffffff8002dfa3b9
0xffffff9238053fb0 : 0xffffff8002cb5dc6

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: adb

Mac OS version:
16A201w

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.0.0: Fri Jun  3 13:56:38 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3705.0.0.1.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 79D0A860-C130-3371-AB9B-3772AE60777B
Kernel slide:     0x0000000002a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8002c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8002b00000
System model name: MacBookPro11,5 (Mac-06F11F11946D27C5)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 19949337419569
last loaded kext at 18286149408268: com.devguru.driver.SamsungACMData   1.4.32 (addr 0xffffff7f87006000, size 86016)
last unloaded kext at 17714940195824: com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver  127 (addr 0xffffff7f86f4a000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.devguru.driver.SamsungACMData   1.4.32
com.devguru.driver.SamsungACMControl    1.4.32
com.devguru.driver.SamsungMTP   1.4.32
com.devguru.driver.SamsungComposite 1.4.32
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    6.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.4
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   275.68
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.13.45
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.0d59
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.1.8
com.apple.AMDRadeonX4000    1.4.4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 5.0.0d59
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.13.45
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.52.0
com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller    1.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 396
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 95
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTopCaseDriver  95
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  292
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1100.25.1a7
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  324
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  360
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   165
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 275.68
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   141
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   5.0.0d59
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.0d59
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.0d59
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    259
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 275.68
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 275.68
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.9
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.13.45
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.4.4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.13.45
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   391
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  126.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   391
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   194
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  355.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    69
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    530
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    287
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 439.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro11,5, BootROM MBP114.0172.B09, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,5 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.30f2
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M370X, AMD Radeon R9 M370X, PCIe, 2048 MB
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x152), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.149.34.1a7)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.0d59, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512G, 500,28 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Comment: macOS Sierra is very early beta, beta software is expected to have bugs, lot's of bugs. Apple suggests not to install beta software on production computers. If you do not want to use buggy software don't install it. File a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: @zaph In addition, I'm using still Xcode 7.3.1 well in Sierra to develop iOS Apps not Beta 8.0 version. Is there a problem with macOS Sierra to be confirmed my first iOS app by Apple?

Comment: I don't see a problem submitting an app made on a Mac running Sierra as long as the Xcode is a released version, not a beta. (Notice the hedge at the beginning of the comment).